# How to wait for ajax to get data, using JSON, before continuing execution?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm creating a program that gets data from a server using AJAX/JSON and then used that data to draw onto a canvas (html5). I have a function that when called, does some initialization and then calls this function:

```
function getClimateData(climateElement) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Climate/yearInformation" + climateElement,
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            weatherData = data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            // Note: just for debugging purposes!
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState +
                    "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    )
};
```

The problem is that before all the data has arrived, the calling function continues and draws some stuff on my canvas, based on the data (which isn't there). This only happens sometimes.

How can I make sure the data has arrived before execution continues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the work…

```
    success: function (data) {
        weatherData = data;
        // <------------------ HERE! 
    },
```

… and not in the calling function.

That is the point of having a callback function.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but unfortunately this means a lot of reconstruction since I didn't think of this to begin with. But I guess that's my only choice if no one has a magic solution :)

Comment: Scratch that, I made the change and it wasn't that big a deal, works like a charm now, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the code that draws based on the data to a separate function call in the success function - or just put the code directly in the success function.

```
...
success: function (data) { 
  // use data to do your drawing
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to put the request into synchronous mode using `async: false` but it's usually a bad idea.

The best way to deal with this is to change your script's structure so everything dependent on the request happens in the success callback (or gets called from there).

Answer (score 0):

You should put the drawing function in your success callback. This way, the drawing functionality is only triggered when the data arrives.